# How can I add filteration drop down on a specific column in datatable plugin along with searching and sorting

Tags: jquery, datatables, filtering

I am using a plugin [http://datatables.net/](http://i60.tinypic.com/4jntow.png) for my php application on thead of each column of a table  i am giving user a facility  to search and as well sort individual column now i want to add filtration for each column on the click event of DataTable following is my jQuery code

## code to append input for searching for column

```js
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     $('#table2 thead th').slice(3).each(function () {
            var title = $('#table2 thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
            if ($(this).hasClass('disableColumn')) {
                $(this).html('<label>' + title + '<label/>');
            } else {
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
            }
        });
```

## here is my datatable

```js
 var table = $('#table2').DataTable({
        "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
      
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

        columnDefs: [{
            targets: 'disableColumn', 
            orderable: false
        }],
//     "iDisplayLength": 10,
//        "bJQueryUI": true,
//        "bFilter": true, 
  
        "aaSorting": [],
        "colVis": {
            "activate": "click",
            "showAll": "Show all",
            "showNone": "Show none",
            "restore": "Restore",
            "bRestore": true,
            "scrollY": "200px",
            "stateSave": true,
            "buttonText": "Select Column",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "exclude": [0, 1, 2],
            "label": function (index, title) {
                var getplaceholder = $(title).attr('placeholder');
                var getlabel = $(title).text();
                if (typeof getplaceholder === 'undefined') {
                    return getlabel;
                } else {
                    return getplaceholder;
                }
            }
        }
       
    });
```

To show the result for searching i am doing like this

```js
  var tableResult = table.columns().eq(0);
    if (tableResult !== null) {
        tableResult.each(function (colIdx) {
            $('input', table.column(colIdx).header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                table
                        .column(colIdx)
                        .search(this.value)
                        .draw();
            });
        });
    }
```

## to disable sorting onClick event for searching  i am using stopPropagation function so that it only sort on the click of sort icon

```js
function stopTableSorting(e) {
        if (!e)
            var e = window.event;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation)
            e.stopPropagation();
    }
    $("#table2 thead tr th input").click(function (e) {
        stopTableSorting(e);
    });
```

Now i want another icon in thead along with input field (Searching) and sort icon which is filtration icon () as a drop down.
Google Docs is also giving this functionality see the image please
[google docs](http://imgh.us/googledocs.png)

I am using this property of datatable but couldn't able to define event listener only for filteration icon and a dropdown just like in Google Docs

```js
initComplete: function () {
            var api = this.api();
 
            api.columns().indexes().flatten().each( function ( i ) {
                var column = api.column( i );              
                var select = $('<i class="fa fa-filter"></i>').slice(3)
                    .appendTo( $(column.header()) )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
                console.log(val);
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '' );//<ul><li value="'+d+'">'+d+'</li></ul>
                } );
            } );
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get similar functionality by using [jQWidget - jQxGrid](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/sorting.htm). It provides you Sorting, Filters and Searching options on DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

you may looking for [this](http://coderexample.com/datatable-custom-column-search/) type of solution. I found that solution is for server side.

if you wanna stick to client side searching only you have to remove ajax link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable();
        $('.search-input-text').on( 'keyup click', function () {   // for text boxes
            var i =$(this).attr('data-column');  // getting column index
            var v =$(this).val();  // getting search input value
            dataTable.columns(i).search(v).draw();
        });
});
```

Comment: I have achieved this already searching for individual column now i can a drop down filter along with this search and in dropdown i have to show list of Values with chekbox so that user can show/hides those specific set of values in the list

Comment: okay. this is kind a [column visibilty](http://awesomescreenshot.com/05f4q8bz57). have check [this](http://coderexample.com/datatable-colvis-column-visibility-customization/) link.